# Adding a new maven dependency causes ArtifactDescriptorException error

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am adding a new maven dependency my project :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding this, I have an error on the Overview page of the POM file :

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.deeplear

I tried to clean and restart the project but it didn't resolve the issue.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on deeplearning4j platform, they suggested to recreate the project with Intellij Idea, not Eclipse. I was using Eclipse, it might have problems with building maven dependencies. When I tried with Intellij, the problem solved.